# bash hangs when exec > > is called and an additional bash script is executed with output to stdin

Tags: bash

I'm calling a bash script from a bash script, however I'm getting left with the script waiting until I press "Enter" or perhaps some other key as well under specific and unexpected circumstances.  I have cut out the detail and simplified the issue to this:

When the script is executed, it will wait for me to press enter until I am returned to the prompt `[user@hostname folder]$`.

Even if test2.sh (detailed below) only has an echo statement in it, I get the same behavior.

**test1.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
exec > >(tee -a "_install_log")
./test2.sh
```

**test2.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
command -v ls  #can find this command and exits with output
#command -v nosuchfile #can't find this command and exits without output.
```

If I uncomment line 3 in *test2.sh* and comment out line 2, this causes *test2.sh* to not have any output to stdin,  then my *test1.sh* script exits properly.  Also, if I remove or comment out the *exec* line, my script exits properly.

Anybody know why this is, and how to prevent it?

- CentOs 7.6.1810 (Core)
- Bash 4.2.46(2)-release

EDIT:  I am not getting this behavior on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.10 (Santiago) with Bash 4.1.2(1)-release

Comment: That's not even valid syntax; it needs to be `exec > >(...)`, with no space between the second `>` and the `(`. The first `>` is the normal "redirect to the file named by the next token" operator; whereas `>( ... )` is a *process substitution*, which turns into a name that can be used to address the stdin of the code running `...`; it's its own syntactic construct, so you can't just add extra spaces and expect the code to still parse correctly.

Comment: With that fixed (and I assume it's correct in your real script and the bug was just added when asking the question), the bigger issue is that when you run it through a process substitution, your stdout is *delayed*, so there's no guarantee that it will have finished printing before the parent process exits and the interactive shell that started it displays its prompt.

Comment: BTW, I moved my answer to the linked duplicate, since I don't see any of the instances there covering bash 4.4's ability to collect (and `wait` for) the PID of a process substitution.

Comment: I don't consider this a duplicate of the other question.  I have no issues with in script output or output from other scripts, but only in the specific test case of calling an additional script.

Comment: I have no intention of displaying a prompt from an interactive shell, but to execute an additional script with parameters as input and an exit code as output.  However any stdin output from the child script should print out to the terminal.  The larger script compiles several packages from source, installs packages from yum, and considerable other things.  I can source the script, but that seems more like a hack to work around something I don't understand well.  Thank you all for your input.

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/charles-dyfis-net/70e5c50fd77e3acf0e0b1cfe6f2f8452 showing what I get when I run your code, and with an explanation of why that output is expected if you have (only!) the problem described in the linked duplicate. If there's an additional, still-outstanding problem, please spell out exactly how to reproduce it.

Comment: (I've edited that gist to *also* show my transcript of invocation and output when the fix proposed in the linked question is applied).

Comment: Charles I appreciate your work, but I do not want a prompt.  This IS the problem.  I want a bash script that outputs to the console and logs to a file when invoked, that can also execute other scripts that also get output and logged, I do NOT want another prompt.  I don't care if it outputs or not, it isn't supposed to even be there.  However, that does explain why in other iterations I had a dang prompt in my output that shouldn't exist.

Comment: You're saying you have an **unwanted** prompt? Why isn't that statement anywhere in your question? The question says, and I quote: *When the script is executed, it will wait for me to press enter until I am returned to the prompt*. As I read it, that's what you're saying *is a bug* -- that you don't get a prompt rendered until you press enter after your script runs, as opposed to the normal/expected behavior of getting the prompt back as soon as your script exits. Is that not what you meant to say?

Comment: ...perhaps a demonstration of the same sort I put in the gist would help, showing precise reproduction steps and both your actual and intended output? I'm happy to reopen a question once it's clearly disambiguated from existing knowledgebase entries (and otherwise on-topic), but I'm evidently still failing to understand what it is you actually meant to ask.

Comment: ...actually, waitaminute. An *unwanted* prompt is **also** consistent with the flagged duplicate (and with the explanation of that duplicate in the gist!). Remember how `tee` is running asynchronously, so when its output is printed isn't lined up with when your program exits? That means that you can get an unexpected prompt showing up intermingled with your output... *exactly as I show in the gist* (see the `$ /usr/bin/ls` there, with the `$` being the prompt printed by the shell to which your program returns control after exiting, but `/usr/bin/ls` not yet printed by the `tee` process).).